# Center text horizontally and vertically in KonvaJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, konvajs

I have something like this:

```
<Stage>
  <Layer>
    <Rect />
      <Text
        ref={this.text}
        draggable 
        align="center"
      />
  </Layer>
</Stage>
```

The text is aligned in the center, but I need to align it vertically. How can I do this?

I know with plain canvas you can do `textBaseline="center"`, but what's the equivalent for Konva?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Konva v2.3.0` you can use `verticalAlign` property:

```
<Text
  x={20}
  y={20}
  width={150}
  height={50}
  text="vertical align"
  verticalAlign="middle"
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/4xorl71m77